# looking for query to return the previous row value from the same field

Tags: sql

i have a vehicle maintenance table which looks like.
table name maintenance. columns are.

```
AssetID    mileage  Hrs  sertype      Covered Mileg
LF-310      1000    200    F1
LF-310      2000    400    F2
LF-311      1500    150    F1
LF-311      3000    300    F2
```

can some one help. how to get the last mileage for calculation.

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no concept of "previous row", unless a column specifically defines the ordering.

Comment: As Gordon and Jean have indicated, you need to define the order. From your data, I'm guessing a date would be sensible ? do you have a date/time column in there somewhere ? (ie the date/time when the meaintenance was done on)?  That would give us an order .. without it .. (or some other order instructions) .. you can't answer this.

Comment: For Example Asset ID LF-310 FIRST MILEAGE IS 1000 AT F1 SERVICE AND AT THE 2ND SERVICE MILEAGE IS 2000. SO I WANT TO GET RESULT IN COVERED MILEAGE 1000

Comment: yes i have date column also in table.

Answer (score 0):

If I can understand your question correctly, this query solve your problem :

```
--DROP TABLE WORK_SHOP

Create Table WORK_SHOP
(
AssetID  VARCHAR(10),
mileage int,
Hrs int,
sertype char(2)
)

INSERT INTO WORK_SHOP
VALUES('LF-310', 1000, 200 ,'F1'),
  ('LF-310', 2000, 400 ,'F2'),
  ('LF-311', 1500, 150 ,'F1'),
  ('LF-311', 3000, 300 ,'F2')

SELECT * 
FROM(
SELECT AssetID,mileage,Hrs,sertype,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AssetID      
                           order by mileage) AS ROW_NUMBER
FROM WORK_SHOP) AS A
WHERE A.ROW_NUMBER =1
```